# How do I utilize the input() command to include ANSI escape color codes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm relatively new to Python. I'm trying to utilize the input() function to include ANSI color codes, and store the values to a dictionary. I've tried using the colorama library too but wanted to try using this approach.

```
red = '\x1b[91m'
reset = '\x1b[0m'

color = input()
```

The user then types in the input:  `red+'test'+reset` which should return `'\x1b[91mtest\x1b[0m'` and printing this input via `print(color)` should return the string 'test' that is colored red.

The `input()` turns it into a string `"red+'test'+rest"` instead. I've also tried directly typing in the ANSI code but I get the string `"\\x1b[91mtest\\x1b[0m"` instead. Is there a way to format it so I can choose anywhere in the string to add colors? e.g. if I wanted this script to get inputs and function like:

```
"The "+yellow+"sun"+reset+" is bright in the "+blue+"sky"+reset+" today."
```

Comment: `input()` just returns the input as a string, it doesn't do any interpretation of it. If you want to interpret it in some way, you have to program that yourself. You could use `eval(input())`, but that's dangerous because the user can type any expression, not just color codes.

Comment: Ahh thanks! Is there a way to make eval() not dangerous? Like if I changed it to str(eval(input()))?

Comment: Basically, you are looking to design a [domain-specific language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language): your user will enter a string in that language, you will parse it, then evaluate the resulting parse tree. If you assume your DSL is a subset of Python, you can use the `ast` module to parse the string first, then safely manipulate the resulting AST instead of using `eval` to evaluate *arbitrary* Python code.

Comment: For example, `red+'test'+rest` can be parsed into something containing both `Name` elements (which you can map to the correct ANSI sequences) and `Constant` elements (which you can treat as literal strings to combine with the ANSI escape sequences). Any nodes that correspond to something you *don't* want to evaluate can be ignored, treated as an error, etc, without actually executing Python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need `eval`

```py
red = '\x1b[91m'
reset = '\x1b[0m'

color = eval(input('Enter something: '), {'red': red, 'reset': reset})
print(color)
```

Output:

```
Enter something: red + 'hi' + reset + 'bye'
```

Prints `hibye` but the `hi` is red and the `bye` is white.

---

**Note: `eval` can be dangerous, don't let the user enter something like `__import__('shutil').rmtree('/')`** - you might want to check the input before `eval`uating. Adding `'__builtins__': None` to the dictionary passed as the second parameter in `eval` may make it a bit safer (as suggested by martineau)

Comment: You can make the use of `eval()` somewhat safer by including a `'__builtins__': None` entry in the dictionary passed to it. This prevents direct access to all of Python's ‘built-in’ identifiers (like `open()`).